# CRM create a new instance of CrmConnection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm definitive new on Dynamic CRM 2011, so maybe this question is really easy.
I'm connecting throw a WCF Service to **different** instances of CRM whit this part of code:

```
 var settings = new ConnectionStringSettings("Xrm", connectionString);

 var connection = new CrmConnection(settings);

 using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(connection))
 {
    //do the magic here
 }
```

The "connectionString" parameter, is a string containing the connection string of the CRM.

So, the problem is that the first time it's connects fine to the server that I write in the connectionString, but then, It always connect to the same server, I mean, even if I change the server address, always tries to connect to the first one.

Debugging, I look in the

```
var connection = new CrmConnection(settings);
```

And is always the same connection to the first server....

So, I need a way to dispose that connection, or force the constructor to always create a new instance... or something like that...
But I can't find the method, or operation that do that...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution, I don't know if is the best solution, but it works...
Instead of using this

```
var settings = new ConnectionStringSettings("Xrm", connectionString);
var connection = new CrmConnection(settings);
```

I use

```
var connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
```

That's giving me the same result, and always with the right connection string

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue here is that some properties are cached for each `ConnectionStringSettings`. You can avoid this by giving using a unique name for each instance (eg: Xrm1, Xrm2 etc). I'm not sure thus behaviour is explicitly documented in the SDK but I've certainly encountered it and fixed it as I indicated.